# twitter bootstrap 3 datepicker doesnt work when the calendar is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using this repo: 
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

I selected the features I wanted for the datepicker and used all the correct libraries. When I click on the box looking icon to display the calendar dropdown, nothing happens. And while using firefox, in firebug no errors are reported. Can someone please point out what the problem can be?

tahnks

btw, on the datepicker site i selected "component" for type. So you know what im talking about when i mean boxed icon.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="bsdp-css" href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="input-group date" style="width:400px;">
<input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector "#sandbox-container" is the parent node of the <kbd>DIV</kbd> with "input-group date" class in the demo site.
You need to add a <kbd>DIV</kbd> tag outside. Then the <kbd>I</kbd> tag with glyphicon-th class can be pressed.
Please refer to http://jsbin.com/lerojivu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. The datepicker js link is wrong, should be: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
2. minViewMode: 1 may wrong

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/yHQ4t/

```
$(function(){$('#dateBox').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yy",
    //minViewMode: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but when i view that jsfiddle and click on the icon nothing happens. i am using, firefox 27.0.1 and chrome 33.0.1750.149. i'll have to check on another computer as well.